# How to add data to POST request body as Form data

Tags: java, android

i am working on an implementation where i need to call a post api which expects the body as the form-data, but don't know to how to set the data as the form-data.
Here is my request

The form-data look like this:
`username: admin123 password: 12345`

//Calling web service request

```
  private static String requestServer(String baseUrl, String jsonRequestString, boolean isHeader) {
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    String jsonResponseString = null;
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    try {
        if (AppUtil.isEmptyString(baseUrl))
            return null;
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl);

        if(httpURLConnection != null)
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        setUpConnectionProperty(httpURLConnection, isHeader);
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        try {
            jsonResponseString = executeConnectionTask(httpURLConnection, jsonRequestString);
          
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (httpURLConnection != null) {
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponseString;
}
```

//setup connection property

```
 private static void setUpConnectionProperty(HttpURLConnection urlConnection, boolean isHeader) {
    if (urlConnection != null) {
        try {
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(RestServiceConstant.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod(RestServiceConstant.REQUEST_TYPE_POST);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty(RestServiceConstant.REQUEST_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE_KEY, RestServiceConstant.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

//After successful connection execute request

```
   private static String executeConnectionTask(HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection, String requestString) {
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    StringBuffer buffer = null;
    /*write request string on output stream*/
    try {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        bufferedWriter.write(requestString);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } finally {
        if (bufferedWriter != null) {
            try {
                bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 ...
 }
```

Comment: `a post api which expects the body as the form-data, ` Well that does not match `String jsonRequestString`.

Comment: I will convert the String data to the form-data. In react native we create form-data like `FormData formdata = new FormData()` then add the key value pair to the formdata, but in android I don't know how to create FormData.

Comment: I think its named ContentValues.